# How do I create a Cocoa touch template using the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I downloaded the free iphone sdk. Now when I try to create a new project I am not given the option to create a cocoa touch template. I only have the option to create a Mac OS X template. Does anyone know why this would occur and how to fix it?

Edit: if you start then restart a download does that damage the downloaded material?

Comment: Try and use real titles for your questions if you can.  I fixed it.

Comment: As I interpret the question, the title should be more like "Cocoa touch template not showing using the iPhone SDK"

Answer (score 0):

You certain you downloaded the whole iPhone SDK, and not just the Xcode updates?
For a repair, I think your looking at a re-install of your tools.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you meet the minimum requirements of the iphone sdk.  I'm guessing you are probably on a PowerPC based Mac which is not (officially) supported.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you downloaded it correctly. Your templates should be up and ready. A redownload should do the trick. (I know, it's a drag)

"Lounges" makes a point though. You're running the SDK on an intel based Mac? That's a requirement, as is running Mac OS X v10.5.5 or later.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the application in a different place make sure you update your dock icons to point to the version you think you want.